# VS Code Extension Development: possible to unregister an event handler

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension, I'd like to register an event listener when the user issues a command but unregisters the listener (or update the listener to something else) when the user issues another command.

For instance, at the end of command A, I register `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` to be something (in my case I registered it to the command A handler). At the end of command B, I'd like to unregister this registration. I understand `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` will return a Disposable, but I don't know how I would pass this disposable to command B.

My code structure is this:

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('A', () => {commandA()});
vscode.commands.registerCommand('B', () => {commandB()});

commandA() {
...
vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(() => {commandA();})
}

commandB() {
...
// How do I unregister the event listener?
}
```

Comment: save the handle in a (global) variable and call the `dispose()` method in `commandB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it using the tip from @rioV8 in the comments. Refactor the code into the structure of your needs like a class.

```
let changeHandle = null;
vscode.commands.registerCommand('A', commandA);
vscode.commands.registerCommand('B', commandB);

commandA() {
  if (!changeHandle)
    changeHandle = vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(commandA);
}

commandB() {
  changeHandle?.dispose();
  changeHandle = null;
}
```

Comment: See more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#events

Comment: To make this work, you also need to set `changeHandle = null;` at the end of commandB(). But thanks! This works.

Comment: @Go_printf You're right. Will update the code accordingly.